# Indexing on nested form with multiple `fields_for`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, fields-for

Given the model `Album` has_many `Song` and the latter with localized fields such as:

```
Song#name_en
Song#description_en
Song#name_fr
Song#description_fr
[...]
```

Due to the frontend design, I can't do one `f.simple_fields_for :songs` in one place for all the song attributes, but need to split it:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :songs do
  = render partial: 'song_en_fields', locals: { f: f, locale: :en }
[...]
= f.simple_fields_for :songs do
  = render partial: 'song_fields', locals: { f: f, locale: :fr }
[...]
```

The resulting fields are indexed with `[0]`, `[1]` etc as they should, however, the index doesn't restart with 0 on each indvidivual `simple_fields_for`, but just keeps counting up.

I've checked the source and found an `index` option in Rails' `fields_for`, but this just adds an additional index array.

Is there a way to "reset" the auto-increment of the index when `simple_fields_for` (or `fields_for`) is invoked multiple times for the same collection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of trying to reset the autoincrement, you could set the index yourself by putting `fields_for` in a loop and passing `child_index: your_index` to it.

Comment: Yep, I just came here to post the same solution. `child_index` does seem to be completely undocumented, at least it's not mentioned anywhere [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for).